# How do I handle this case (value to classify dosn't exist under node) using decision tree?

Tags: classification, decision-tree, decisiontreeclassifier

I implemented decision tree and let's say for example the following tree is what i got :

[image]

and my instance to classify is educationField = '2' and departement = 'HR'

How can i handle this ? i thought of taking the max class where educationField = 2
So the prediction will be YES, will  this  be correct ?